# SVG text element needs different position values for Chrome and IE

Tags: internet-explorer, svg

### [DEMO](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aLvdYd?editors=1100)

[image]

Sorry the demo code is a bit long, but the element in question is
`<text ... class="pva-mb-nav__steps__number"`
which gives the numbers 1,2,3,4 on the balls.
It has attribute `dominant-baseline=central`

When it has attribute `y=20`, the numbers are in the middle of the balls on Chrome, but too high on IE11.  When `y=25`, good on IE11, too low on Chrome.

Some of its attributes can be set in CSS, as you see it is made lime by CSS.  I think if its position can be adjusted by CSS then let me apply IE-only hack. I tried to put `y=xx` or `dy=xx` or `transform:translate(xx)` in CSS, and none worked.

**Question:** How to put the number in the middle of the balls on both Chrome and IE11?

The SVG needs to scale 100% to its container.

[Edited] Just found that IE11 does not support `dominant-baseline`.  This must be the cause.  Then to middle align the number, must I top-align the number and the ball, then manually calculate a good `dy` value for the text?

Comment: Try using attribute `dominant-baseline` instead of `alignment-baseline`. That will at least fix Firefox.

Comment: @ccprog  Changed as told, thanks

Comment: dy="0.5em" might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `dominant-baseline=central`, put `y=25`